# Checklist field value in Search Results in SXA

Tags: sxa

### Introduction

We are using Sitecore 9 Update 2 with SXA 1.7.1.

We have implemented "Download Center" using OOTB search components from SXA.

We would like to show "Title" value of Checklist field instead of GUIDs in Search Results.

We have already created our custom Rendering Variant but it only shows Ids.

### Question

How we can show value of "Title" field instead of indexed GUIDs in search results?

[image]

### Setup of solution

Custom Template that we have created (inherits Foundation interface template _Searchable + adds new fields):
[image]

We have created hierarchy of tags under Data > Tags (we are refering to these from template as can be seen above):

[image]

This is how it looks like on items itself:

[image]

Rendering variant for Search Results (same is also for remaining fields):

[image]

**How we should configure this to show Title field instead of GUID?**

This is how the search results look now:

[image]

Comment: Did you try with a Reference in your variant? Checklist is not in the list of possible fields, but it works for other reference fields, so maybe also for this one..  I'll elaborate in an answer once I know it works with this type of field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Reference` in your variant.

> **Reference**: displays field from referenced item. If you want to display
>   a field from a referenced item, you can define this field in the
>   PassThroughField. You can use this variant field for the following
>   fields: LinkField (GeneralLink, DropLink), FileField (File),
>   ImageField (Image), and ReferenceField (Droptree). Reference items can
>   contain have another reference item as its child item. This can be
>   convenient when you want to create a tree of reference items and
>   display fields from items which are referenced in referenced items.

Although the official doc (as above) don't mention you fieldtypes, I just tested with a CheckList field and that worked just fine.

So: create in your variant definition a child of type "Reference". And underneath the reference, a child of type "Field". In the reference item pass the fieldname from your item (e.g. "Topic") and in the field item use the fienldname of the topic template (probably "Title").